# Set cookie when button clicks for 6 times and disable clicking

Tags: jquery, cookies, limit

Im trying to make a button limit for clicking just six times, and then make it unclickable for 30 mins, even if you reload the page it must be disable, but after 30 mins show button again without reload page, Is that possible? I need help.

Here is the code:

```
(function(){
    var click_counter = 0;
    jQuery('.controls_next').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var el = jQuery(this);
        click_counter += 1;
        if (!el.hasClass('')){
            // should be activated
        };
        if (click_counter >= 6){
            // deactivate
            el.addClass('disabled');
            var date = new Date();
            var minutes = 01;
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
            $.cookie("skipSongCookie", { expires: date });
        };
    });
})();
```

Comment: what's the porblem you are facing? by the way, you need to do you check on page load also.

Answer (score 0):

you can set cookie and change value :

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays)
{
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays === null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Comment: can u make all together please how to write exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else
        var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function checkCookie(name, days)
{
    var value = readCookie(name);
    if (value === null) {
        createCookie(name, 1, days);
    } else {
        value += 1;
        createCookie(name, value + 1, days)
    }
    return value;
}
$(function() {
    var name = 'cookie_name';
    var days = 365;
    $('.controls_next').click(function() {
        var click_counter = checkCookie(name, days);
        if(click_counter >= 6){
            $('.controls_next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            // or $('.controls_next').addClass('disabled');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: This didn't work bro :( but THANK YOU anyway for your time, i appreciate.

Comment: What i need is simple, When user click the Button for X Times automatically Disable or HIDE it and must set a cookie for X Minutes too, to make it HIDE even you reload the page, And after X Minutes gone, to Enable or SHOW button again, This is what i need Thank You and Im sorry for your time u spend for me :)